# How to connect Ksql with ibm-cloud event-stream?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ksqldb

we created a project with ibm functions and event-streams in IBM Cloud.

Now, I am trying to connect KSQL with IBM cloud Event Stream, and I am following along the [Document](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/EventStreams/eventstreams110.html#ksql_using) for getting basic ideas of integration.

By following the instructions, I created a file called `ksql-server.properties` and modified `bootstrap.servers`, `username`, `password` according to my credentials. Then I ran `ksql http://localhost:8088 --config-file ksql-server.properties` with ksql local cli. I assume everying runs correctly so far since the `ksql>` shows in the front of every new line...

Then I decided to check if the ksql connected with my ibm cloud by running `SHOW topics;`

Turns out some error lines:

```
    `Error issuing POST to KSQL server. path:ksql'`
    `Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to set 'ssl.protocol' to 'TLSv1.2' (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.KsqlRequest["streamsProperties"])`
    `Caused by: Failed to set 'ssl.protocol' to 'TLSv1.2' (through reference chain: io.confluent.ksql.rest.entity.KsqlRequest["streamsProperties"])
    `
    `Caused by: Failed to set 'ssl.protocol' to 'TLSv1.2'`
    `Caused by: Cannot override property 'ssl.protocol'`
```

Also, I am quick lost at step 4 when it tells me to: 
        `Then start DataGen twice as follows:

```
    i. With bootstrap-server=HOSTNAME:PORTNUMBER quickstart=users format=json topic=users maxInterval=10000 to start creating users events.

    ii. With bootstrap-server=HOSTNAME:PORTNUMBER quickstart=pageviews format=delimited topic=pageviews maxInterval=10000 to start creating pageviews events.`
```

Is there anyone have done this before or would love to help me out? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IBM document is very out of date. KSQL runs as a client/server. The server needs to be run with the details of the broker, and then you can connect to it with a client, including the CLI, REST API, or web interface provided by Confluent Control Center.

So you need to run the KSQL server using your properties file:

```
./bin/ksql-server-start ksql-server.properties
```

and then connect to it with the CLI (for example):

```
./bin/ksql http://localhost:8088
```

See https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/installing.html for more information.

Comment: Thanks to your help, I am moving forward! I think the config file in ibm document is out-date too. Based on their config file parameters, I added `ksql.sink.replicas=3`. Then I added  `ksql.streams.retention.ms=3600000` because of error message: `Failed to guarantee existence of topic _confluent-ksql-default__command_topic. Invalid retention period specified. The minimum is an hour and the maximum is 30 days. This must be specified as a multiple of 3,600,000`.

Comment: Then I decided to create a topic ` _confluent-ksql-default__command_topic` manually. After creation, I got `Failed to set config for Kafka Topic _confluent-ksql-default__command_topic The minimum is an hour and the maximum is 30 days. This must be specified as a multiple of 3,600,000`. Do you have any advice for getting rid of this error?

Comment: My advice would be to download Confluent Platform, get KSQL working against local Kafka brokers with that, and then explore how to hook it up to wherever you are running your brokers. Or check out confluent.cloud ;-) ;-)